# Applying K-means clustering on Z-score Normalized Data

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, data-mining, k-means

I've been working to understand how to apply k-means clustering to a small set of data for a list of companies.

The mean and standard deviation is given so that I can determine the normalized data.

For example, I have the following:

[image: zscore]

From my understanding of k-means clustering, I have to randomly find the centroids, where k = 3. I have to keep adjusting the centroid locations until no more movements are possible, that is the data remains the same after a certain result is met.

I am having difficulty applying these procedures to my data set. I've watched and searched for many examples on how to accomplish this, step by step, but I haven't had any success that allows me to understand.

Basically what I am suppose to do is show a scatter plot at each adjustment to the centroid.

I believe that I have to calculate the distance between two data items using the Euclidean distance algorithm, but does that mean the distance between z-score sales and z-score fuel, or what? This is why I am lost, even after I've read through about a dozen powerpoints and watched multiple videos.

This seems to be the best example I've come across, but even then, I'm still a bit lost due to my example being slightly different than the one introduced: http://www.indiana.edu/~dll/Q530/Q530_kk.pdf

The most progress I've made was coming across a variety of data mining software, such as WEKA, Orange, various Excel add-ons such as XLMiner, etc. However, they seem to provide the end result, not the procedures required to get there.

Any help is appreciated. If more information is needed, please let me know.

Thank you.

**Edit:** I've found some more solutions and thought I should add in the event anyone runs into the same issues.

1) I calculated the Euclidean distance using this Excel formula mentioned on this video: http://www.lynda.com/Excel-tutorials/Calculating-distance-centroid/165438/175003-4.html

---

This is what the formula looks like: `=SQRT((B28-$B$52)^2+(C28-$C$52)^2)` keeping in mind that each cell represents where your data is contained.

In this case my cells are listed in the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BduB5.png

This has given me the following table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkb7z.png

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right on with the process.  Personally, I'd view your data as 2D just the (x,y) that are Sales and Fuel Cost... though you could use all 4 and just have 4D points instead.

**Step 1**: Either pick random centers (3 of them c_1, c_2, c_3), or split up your data into 3 random clusters.  If you randomly split the data into 3 clusters, you then compute the mean of all the points in each cluster.  Those 3 means become the three centers.  (Here by mean, I mean the average of each coordinate... think of them as vectors and average the vector.)

**Step 2**: Each center represents one of the three clusters.  For each point, compute the distance to each center (this could be Euclidean distance, or any other distance metric).  Each point is moved into the cluster whose center is the closest.  I.e. if point i is closest to center j, then regardless of which cluster point i was in, it moves to cluster j.  Keep track of whether or not any point moves to a new cluster.  This is used as a part of your stopping condition in Step 3.

**Step 3**: After all the points have moved to the cluster nearest them, recompute the centers by averaging together all the points in each cluster.  Then, go back to 2 and repeat until no points change which cluster they are in.

Comment: If you have questions about how to compute the means, distances, etc, let me know and I will elaborate (and/or post relevant links).

Comment: To output what you are looking for, perhaps you want to plot the points colored by which cluster they are in: points in cluster 1, red; points in cluster 2, green; points in cluster 3, blue.  Then plot the centers with the same color but a distinct shape/size.  You can update the plot after each iteration of step 2 and step 3.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did the following:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/EIGv6YF.png)
---
From here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/VtIlv9k.png), I added all the values **(-1.0778) + (-1.5814) + (-0.775) = -3.4342 / 3 = -1.1456** and so on for the rest of the values. Is this correct?

Also, now that I have the first centroid coordinates, how do I proceed? What do I do with those numbers?

Comment: That will give you the mean of the z-fuel scores (the x-component it looks like) for the red cluster.  So that is how you compute the mean for each coordinate for each cluster.  After you do this, then look at each point and see which mean it is closes to (using the distance formula).  Then reclassify the points so that they are in the cluster with closest mean.  You are definitely on the right track.  It is probably hard to do this in excel (you may have to iterate a number of times especially if there's a lot of data).

Comment: I'm glad I'm on the right track. That's reassuring...I'm usually in left field when trying to solve things.  

So what I think I have to do now is use the values that I just computed with the normalized data to determine the distance from each centroid. This will essentially position the centroid and reestablish the points associated with the cluster? I can imagine this being useful for large sets of data, but for my small set of data it's quite negligible. I could be wrong.